# In HTML, how can I wrap a word at . (dot), just like it wraps at - (dash)?

Tags: html, css

I have a long word in a table cell that messes up the table layout:

a.long.word.separated.by.dots

I would like the word to wrap like this word:

a-long-word-separated-by-dashes

How can I get this done, with CSS, without changing the HTML?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Might not be possible with CSS only.

Comment: Then my answer is just for future readers. @Simon

Comment: The simple answer to your question is that you can't!

Comment: It's possible with something like php. but I don't think that's something OP has.

Comment: Why can't you use JS?

Comment: As I read in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/css-3-content-selector), seems that you cannot target content text...

Comment: @11684 If there are no other alternatives, I will go with your solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If using JS is okay, you can do this. If it is not, then this answer may still be useful for future readers.

```
var longWord = "a.long.word.separated.by.dots".replace(/\./g, '.<wbr>');
```

Reference on the wbr tag: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/wbr

Alternatively, you could put a `<wbr>` after each period manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in PHP, sorry for waking a dead question, but if you're populating an HTML table using a PHP loop you just need something like:

```
preg_replace('/\./', '.<wbr>', $string);
```

This takes [11684's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16031172/6331313) and puts it into the requested context.

Answer (score 0):

`<wbr>` didn't work for me, but a zero-width space did. You can use:

```
var longWord = "a.long.word.separated.by.dots".replace(/\./g, '.&#x200b;');
```

Comment: A downside of using a zero-width space is that it will be copied to the clipboard if the user copies text from the Web page. This could cause a lot of confusion depending on what application the text ends up in.

Comment: @kindall you are right. Fortunately, that's not an issue in my case - the text is not selectable.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this CSS3 property:

```
table tr td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap

Comment: It wraps at any character, not only at punctuation.